# How after Send Email get ID Message and send Followup

Tags: google-apps-script

I have google docs with new users with name. My script send Message every day (6 pm) with welcome message and add in doc ( date send, information send first message). Next after 3 days for first mails. Script send first Followup 1 and add information in doc. After 7 day script send last email with Followup 2. My script is works! 
But I have problem because My script send every time NEW email not send mail with thread.

I don't know how get id message from first message and send followup 1 and followup 2 in threads.

This is my Doc : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYL1B.jpg

````
  var docsID = SpreadsheetApp.openById("My_id_docs");
  var sheet1 = docsID.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = docsID.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var addressEmailSender = "My_EMAIL";

  var emailSubject = sheet2.getRange("C1").getValues();
  var emailContent = sheet2.getRange("A2").getValues();

  var emailFollowup1Subject = sheet2.getRange("C4").getValues();
  var emailFollowup1Content = sheet2.getRange("A5").getValues();

  var emailFollowup2Subject = sheet2.getRange("C8").getValues();
  var emailFollowup2Content = sheet2.getRange("A9").getValues();

  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var now = new Date();

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var tempTime = sheet2.getRange("B14");
    var CategoryMail = sheet1.getRange(i, 1).getValues();
    var Answer = sheet1.getRange(i, 8).isBlank();
    var UserEmail = sheet1.getRange(i, 9).getValues();

    if (CategoryMail == "Other" && Answer && UserEmail.length > 0 ) {
      var userName = sheet1.getRange(i, 10).getValues();

      if (userName.length > 0) {
        var messageTitle = "Hey " + userName + "," + '\n';
      } else {
        var messageTitle = "Hey," + '\n';
      }

      tempTime.setValue(new Date(now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
      var TestTime = tempTime.getValue().valueOf();

      if(sheet1.getRange(i,2).isBlank()) {
        sheet1.getRange(i,2).setValue("yes");
        sheet1.getRange(i,5).setValue(new Date(now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
        GmailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, emailSubject, messageTitle + emailContent, {from: addressEmailSender, name: "Buddy"});
        GmailApp.getMessageById(id)
      }
      else {
        var Var0 = sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue().valueOf();
        var Var1 = sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue().valueOf();
        var Var2 = sheet1.getRange(i,7).getValue().valueOf();
        if((TestTime >= Var1 && TestTime < Var2) && sheet1.getRange(i,3).isBlank()  ) {
          sheet1.getRange(i,3).setValue("yes");          
          GmailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, emailFollowup1Subject, messageTitle + emailFollowup1Content, {from: addressEmailSender, name: "Buddy"});
        }
        else if((TestTime >= Var2 && TestTime > Var1) && sheet1.getRange(i,4).isBlank() && sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValues() == "yes") {
          sheet1.getRange(i,4).setValue("yes"); 
          GmailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, emailFollowup1Subject, messageTitle + emailFollowup2Content, {from: addressEmailSender, name: "Buddy"});
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `sendEmail()` function does not return the ID of the thread. If you add yourself as `cc` when you send the email, you can perform a search inbox and then you can get the ID. After this you can [add messages to threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads).

A simpler solution would be using [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) instead of GmailApp. The main difference is with GmailApp you can manage most of the Gmail functions.
Keep in mind that you need to use the same Subject. Also, it has a different syntax:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("mail@example.com", "Subject", "body");
```